# Controller layout- how to successfully return layout with modified content

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to set and return a layout that's attached to a controller.  I can successfully set the content for @yeild('content') but I cannot both set and return the template.  I can either return the template, with no content set, or I can return the set content, with no layout template.

**master.blade.php**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

        @yield('styles')

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Google Earth project!</h1>
            <a href="http://laravel.com/docs/quick">Saucey sauce for laravel</a>
            <hr>
            <h4>Content</h4>

            @yield('content')

        </div>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        @yield('scripts')

    </body>
</html>
```

**HotspotController.php**

```
...
public function show($uid, $lid, $hid)
{
    // $this->layout->content = View::make('hotspot.profile');
    $this->layout->content = 'a string';
    return $this->layout;
}
....
```

Comment: What happend when you try :
return View::make('hotspot.profile');

Comment: The desired template renders successfully, except not in the layout I defined.  A placeholder "I AM A PROFILE TEMPLATE!" string appeared.

Comment: You'r profile.blade.php start with something like :
@extends('layout_path.layout_file.blade.php')

Comment: I don't think that's a good approach.  Look at my answer for a couple alternative ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is apparently a difference between @yield('content') and {{ $content }}.

In order to accomplish what you're trying to accomplish you will have to use the latter way of declaring variable content on the blade template.

**HotspotController.php**

```
protected $layout = 'layouts.master';
...
public function show($uid, $lid, $hid)
{
    $this->layout->content = View::make('hotspot.profile');
}
...
```

**hotspot.profile.blade.php**

```
I am a hotspot profile
```

**master.blade.php**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

        @yield('styles')

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Google Earth project!</h1>
            <a href="http://laravel.com/docs/quick">Saucey sauce for laravel</a>
            <hr>
            <h4>Content</h4>

            {{ $content }}

        </div>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        @yield('scripts')

    </body>
</html>
```

**Alternatively...**

You can keep @yield('content') in your master template, but you will have to modify hotspot.profile.blade.php to incorporate @section('content') @stop.  See hotspot.blade.php

**master.blade.php**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

        @yield('styles')

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Google Earth project!</h1>
            <a href="http://laravel.com/docs/quick">Saucey sauce for laravel</a>
            <hr>
            <h4>Content</h4>

            @yield('content')

        </div>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        @yield('scripts')

    </body>
</html>
```

**hotspot.profile.blade.php**

```
@section('content')
I am a hotspot profile
@stop
```